# CKEditor is adding Â when putting using two spaces on a iso-8859-1 encoded page

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ckeditor

There appears to be a problem with CKEditor that when you use two spaces it converts one to a   entity and the other it keeps as a regular space. The problem is that it using utf-8 encoding for the space, which shows as Â on iso-8859-1 encoded pages.

My guess this is being caused because the js files for CKEditor are saved as UTF-8, so any spaces in the files will be UTF-8 versions.  Thus the wrong character being inserted into iso-8859-1 pages.

Is there any solution to this other than switching to UTF-8 for my DB and page encoding? I do plan on doing this, but not at this time.

Comment: Spaces are encoded the same way in UTF8 and ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Just a guess.. Not sure why this happens, but I am not alone as I found this reported by others

Comment: AFAIK it's enough if CKEditor is served in UTF-8 and the htmlentities plugin is enabled (so `&nbsp;` are encoded in the output). I think that your page and database can be in ISO-8859-1 then. I'm not posting this as an answer because I haven't checked it.

Comment: OK sorry for the delay. Will test this. Not sure if htmlentities plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work unfortunately. I had to convert the page to UTF-8 in order for the symbols to not appear.